# Existence of the complement of product of two normal subgroups having complement

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group. If $H\le G$, $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=1$, then $K$ is called a *complement* of $H$ in $G$. In general complements do not exist. For example, the center of a quaternion group $Q$ does not have a complement since there is only one involution in $Q$; also, nontrivial proper subgroups of cyclic groups of prime power order do not have complements.

There are some nice theorems ensuring the existence of complement under some conditions, like the one of Schur-Zassenhaus and the one of Gaschütz.

When two normal subgroups both have their complements, it can be seen that $N_1N_2$ does not necessarily has complement. But it seems that the complement exists provided that some additional information is given, for example one the two normal subgroups is contained in a complement of another subgroup. So the following question arises:

> Let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be normal subgroups of $G$. If $N_i$ has a complement $L_i$ ($i=1,2$) such that $N_2\le L_1$, then also $N_1N_2$ has a complement.

Is the statement true? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This statement is incorrect: "proper subgroups of cyclic groups do not have complements".

Comment: Also, a couple of times you have written "the complement" when you mean "a complement". The word "the" implies uniqueness. Also it is not clear why you want to assume that $G$ is finite. The problem makes perfect sense for all groups.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I’ve edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that $L_1 \cap L_2$ is a complement of $N_1N_2$ under those hypotheses, without assuming that $G$ is finite.

To show that $G = N_1N_2(L_1 \cap L_2)$, let $g \in G$. Then $g = n_1l_1$ with $n_1 \in N_1$ and $l_1 \in L_1$. Also $l_1 = n_2 l_2$ with $n_2 \in N_2$ and $l_2 \in L_2$. But $N_2 \le L_1$, so $l_2 \in L_1 \cap L_2$.

To show that $N_1N_2 \cap L_1 \cap L_2 = 1$, let $g = n_1n_2 \in L_1 \cap L_2$ with $n_1 \in N_1$, $n_2 \in N_2$. Then $n_2 \in L_1$, so $n_1 \in L_1$, but $N_1 \cap L_1 = 1$, so $n_1=1$, and then $n_2 \in L_2$ implies $n_2=1$.